# Advice on how to pass a JS onchange event to PHP

Tags: php, javascript, mysql

I have three drop down menus that query a MYSQL database depending on what a user selects. One of the menus is dynamic and but I can't get it to return data - the other two work fine. I think i need to catch the JS onchange event and then pass it to PHP in order to run the query but I am going in circles at present.

Below is what i am trying to do. All the values are stored in the `<head>` section - I have added my query and select html and on change event below.

```
$category=$_POST['Category'];
$subcategory=$_POST['Subcategory'];
$destination=$_POST['Destination'];

$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM travel WHERE Category='$category'
AND Subcategory='$subcategory' AND Destination='$destination'")
or die(mysql_error());

$row = mysql_fetch_assoc( $result ) ;


<select name="subcategory" id="subcategory onchange="javascript:
dropdownlist(this.options[this.selectedIndex].value)">
<option value="">Select Sub-Category</option>
```

Comment: Are you looking to pass this event from JavaScript to the server whilst not doing a page reload? If so, you need an AJAX operation. Take a look at the jQuery docs, or search for 'ajax php example'.

Comment: Thanks Halfer, Yes, that's it exactly, The menus works fine, but i have not been able to get Javascript and PHP to do the Job, I will take your advice and look for Ajax PHP examples - Thanks again. Wes Dunn

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#myelement').change(function() {
        $.ajax(
            serverUrl,
            {
                data: { /* Put your input data in here as a hash */ }
                type: 'POST',
                dataType: 'json',
                success: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
                    /* Put your response handler in here */
                }
            }
        );
    });
});
```

I'll leave you to do the server bit - you'll need `json_encode()`. Have fun!

Comment: Thanks Halfer, I was already on my 20th tutorial, I will be sure to thank you again if I work out what to do with the code you kindly gave me :-)